# HTML not loading if Javascript function is added

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I have a jsp page and its facing a strange problem. When I am adding any javascript function, a part of the html is disappearing.
 Eq If I remove the setRent() function, its coming fine is coming. But If I add it, complete html is not loading is coming. Can anybody fix this issue? Thanks in advance.

The viewable part is like :

ROOMNO: 110
ROOMTYPE : AC/NONAC (Drop Down)
ROOMRENT : 1000

If I include the javascript function, it is not loading the html completely(I can see from view Source of html). and its showing:

ROOMRENT:(

ie (000" td> is not loading)

My java Script:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function setRent(){
        alert(">>>>");
    }

</script>
```

My jsp code:

```
 <table class=green width="200" border="1" class="roomDetails" >

  <tr>
    <td width="94" class="bluebtn">ROOM NO</td>
    <td ><bean:write name="occupant" property="roomNo"/>  </td>
  </tr>
   <% if(occ.getOccupancyId()!=null){ %>
  <tr>
    <td class="bluebtn">ROOM TYPE</td>
    <td><bean:write name="occupant" property="roomType"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="bluebtn">ROOM RENT</td>
    <td><bean:write name="occupant" property="roomRent"/></td>
  </tr>
  <% } else{          
      ArrayList<String> list=occ.getRoomlist();

      %>

      <tr>
      <td class="bluebtn">ROOM TYPE</td>
      <td>
      <select name="roomType" id="roomType" onchange="setRent()">
      <%  for(String s: list){
          String [] room=s.split("~~~~~"); %>
        <option value="<%= room[0] %>"><%= room[0] %></option>
      <%   } %>
      </select>
      </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
    <td class="bluebtn">ROOM RENT</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="roomRent" id="roomRent" value="<%= occ.getRoomRent() %>"  disabled="disabled"/></td>
    </tr>

      <%
  } %>


  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your server script gets confused by the code in the function.

Try if avoiding the `>` character in the script helps:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function setRent(){
  alert("\x3e\x3e\x3e\x3e");
}
</script>
```

Comment: I have tried putting "HI" also... doesnt work. Just the mere inclusion of javascript in the code creates the problem. <br>